# How to convert image stream buffer into jpeg image bytes in flutter for iOS?

Tags: image-processing, flutter, dart, camera

When we deal with camera in **flutter**, we use **Camera** plugin.
It has `.startImageStream` method which returns `CameraImage cameraImage` data type.

In iOS, `cameraImage.format` is **bgra8888**.
For android `cameraImage.format` is **yuv420**.

Before encoding these formats to JPEG or PNG, we need some bytes manipulation and put each byte into image buffer, which is then used in `JpegEncoder`.

For android, `cameraImage(yuv420) to List<int>` is discussed and implemented in this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26348#issuecomment-462321428

The question is, how do we construct flutter **Image(jpeg|png)** from **bgra8888** `cameraImage`?

Comment: Can you give me a sample bgra8888 buffer data so I can test ?

Comment: I don't know about bgra8888, but in one of my app, I've used package multi_image_picker which picks the image from iOS Photos app and Camera (as specified). And then you can convert it into bytes or List<int> as desired. Sample code : `ByteData byteData = await asset.requestOriginal();
    List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();` And [here](https://rvitanov.com/selecting-multiple-images-with-flutter) is sample implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `pub.dev` image library API at https://pub.dev/packages/image. It converts from any image format, regardless of it being bgra8888 or yuv420. This example converts it to a PNG file:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart';
void main() {
  // Read an image from file
  // decodeImage will identify the format of the image and use the appropriate
  // decoder.
  Image image = decodeImage(File('test.bgra8888').readAsBytesSync());

  // Resize the image to a 120x? thumbnail (maintaining the aspect ratio).
  Image thumbnail = copyResize(image, width: 120);

  // Save the thumbnail as a PNG.
  File('thumbnail.png').writeAsBytesSync(encodePng(thumbnail));
}
```

Comment: Op requested conversion to JPG, not PNG

Comment: any solution for jpg image??

Comment: the solution for JPG is to rename the file to `thumbnail.jpg` and use the `encodeJpg` method instead of `encodePng`

Comment: then how to set jpg background to white?